# Login modal in ASP.net Core Razor Pages

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, popup, bootstrap-modal, razor-pages

I want to create an asp.net core razor pages (not MVC) program with modal for some of it's functionalities like login, forgot password, etc. I created a razor page for login with a bootstrap modal and a link to open the modal in the frontend and LoginViewModel and RegistrationServices in the backend. How can I use this page to access login modal in all pages?
Can I use Partial view? How? Otherwise, what is the solution?
This is _Login:

```
public class _LoginModel : PageModel
{
    private readonly ICookieAuthenticationService _cookieAuthenticationService;
    private readonly IUserRegistrationService _userRegistrationService;
    private readonly IUserService _userService;

    public _LoginModel(ICookieAuthenticationService cookieAuthenticationService,
        IUserRegistrationService userRegistrationService,
        IUserService userService)
    {
        _cookieAuthenticationService = cookieAuthenticationService;
        _userRegistrationService = userRegistrationService;
        _userService = userService;
    }

    [BindProperty]
    public LoginViewModel LoginViewModel { get; set; }

    [TempData]
    public string ErrorMessage { get; set; }
    
    ...
}
```

I removed @page from _Login and injected services and use this for partial view:

```
<partial name="_Login" model="new _LoginModel(cookieAuthenticationService, userRegistrationService, userService, logService)" />
```

But now the post method does not work because of the removed @page.

Answer (score 0):

> I want to create an asp.net core razor pages (not MVC) program with modal for some of it's functionalities like login, forgot password, etc.

A [partial page](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/mvc/views/partial?view=aspnetcore-5.0) is a Razor markup file (.cshtml) without an `@page` directive, but as you mentioned that if you remove `@page` directive from `_Login.cshtml`, which would cause Razor Page feature, such as page handler(s) etc, not work well anymore.

To achieve the requirement of showing login etc functionality in a modal popup, you can use a additional partial page `_LoginPartial.cshtml`, and make it post to `_Login` handler, like below.

```
@model _LoginModel

<div class="row">
    <div class="col-md-4">
        <section>
            <form method="post" asp-page="_Login">
                <h4>Use a local account to log in.</h4>
                <hr />
                <div asp-validation-summary="All" class="text-danger"></div>
                <div class="form-group">
                    <label asp-for="LoginViewModel.Email"></label>
                    <input asp-for="LoginViewModel.Email" class="form-control" />
                    <span asp-validation-for="LoginViewModel.Email" class="text-danger"></span>
                </div>
                <div class="form-group">
                    <label asp-for="LoginViewModel.Password"></label>
                    <input asp-for="LoginViewModel.Password" class="form-control" />
                    <span asp-validation-for="LoginViewModel.Password" class="text-danger"></span>
                </div>
                <div class="form-group">
                    <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary">Log in</button>
                </div>
            </form>
        </section>
    </div>
</div>
```

*Invoke `_LoginPartial`*

```
<partial name="_LoginPartial" model='...
```

***Update:***

> how to validate inputs before post to new page? things like empty password or invalid user.

[Client-side validation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/mvc/models/validation?view=aspnetcore-5.0#client-side-validation) could help prevent submission until the form is valid. You can use following code in your view page, which would help add required script references that supports client-side validation.

```
@section scripts{ 
    <partial name="_ValidationScriptsPartial" />
}
```

Comment: Thanks. Do you have a better solution than what I described?

Comment: Normally we do use partial view or partial page to achieve this kind of requirements.

Comment: But how to validate inputs before post to new page? things like empty password or invalid user.

Comment: `how to validate inputs before post to new page` You can enable [client-side validation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/mvc/models/validation?view=aspnetcore-5.0#client-side-validation) by invoking `_ValidationScriptsPartial.cshtml` partial.

Comment: Hi @HosseinPour, if the answer did help resolve the issue, kindly accept it - see [What should I do when someone answers my question?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers)